# x86 Assembly(NASM) - Open a file for reading and print the contents

Tags: x86, nasm

I am trying to read some text from a file and print it to the console, but i simply can not get it working. It does not print anything...
(My file just has 5 words of text)
The CreateFile call seems to be working fine.
The ReadFile call returns 0, so that's probably where the problem lies.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
    global  _main
extern  _printf
extern  _ReadFile@20
extern  _WriteFile@20
extern  _GetStdHandle@4
extern  _CreateFileA@28
    extern  _ExitProcess@4

section .data
    fmt:        db '%d', 0Dh, 0Ah, 0    ; newline and NULL terminated
    access:     dd 0x10000000
    filename:   db 'ThisIsATestFile.txt', 0

    buflen:     dd 2048     ; Size of our buffer to be used for read
    dwBytesRead:dw 0

section .bss
    buffer:     resb 2048   ; A 2 KB byte buffer used for read

section .text
_main:
; CreateFile@28 - OpenFile
xor eax, eax
push eax            ; 7 param - Handle
push 128            ; 6 param - FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
push 4              ; 5 param - OPEN_ALWAYS
push eax            ; 4 param - Default security
push eax            ; 3 param - Do not share
push DWORD [access] ; 2 param - Generic All
push filename       ; 1 param - FileName
call _CreateFileA@28

    mov ebx, eax    ; copy the handle into ebx

; ReadFile@20
xor eax, eax
push eax
push dwBytesRead
push buflen
push buffer
push ebx    ; handle
call _ReadFile@20

mov esi, eax    ; get the amount of bytes read

; GetHandle - Output
push -11
call _GetStdHandle@4
mov ebx, eax    ; copy the handle into ebx

; WriteFile@20
xor eax, eax
push eax
push eax
push esi
push buffer
push ebx
call _WriteFile@20




; ExitProcess(0)
    push    0
    call    _ExitProcess@4
```

Thank you so much for the help Ruud. Works like a charm :)
I ended up doing like this with the ReadFile and WriteFile.

```
; ReadFile@20
xor eax, eax
push eax
push dwBytesRead
push DWORD [buflen]
push buffer
push ebx    ; handle
call _ReadFile@20

mov esi, eax

; GetHandle - Output
push -11
call _GetStdHandle@4
mov ebx, eax    ; copy the handle into ebx


; WriteFile@20
add esi, DWORD [dwBytesRead]    ; copy the length into esi

xor eax, eax
push eax
push eax
push esi
push buffer
push ebx
call _WriteFile@20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
push buflen
```

by

```
push DWORD [buflen]
```

You should pass the value there, not a reference.